# Tensor indexing with matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have matrix (3 x 15) `dummies` with sequences of tokens as rows:

```
[[ 1 66 67 68  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 1 66 67 66 68 66 67 66  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 1 66 67 68 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 17  0]]
```

Also, there's a tensor `probs` of shape (3 x 15 x n_tokens) with token probabilities.

From `probs` I need to select only probabilities of tokens in `dummies`.

I think, it may be possible to use the matrix as indices for the tensor, but I haven't found how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dummies = ...
probs = ...
s = tf.shape(dummies)
i = tf.range(s[0])
j = tf.range(s[1])
ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(i, j, indexing='ij')
idx = tf.stack([ii, jj, dummies], axis=-1)
result = tf.gather_nd(probs, idx)
```

Comment: I have 5 dimensions in `result`

Comment: @koPytok Sorry, fixed it, it should be `tf.gather_nd`, not `tf.gather`.